# Binding Image Source vs set Image Source with string

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm having trouble understanding why using strings in XAML to bind to images in the assets folder works, and using strings to set the `Image.Source` in C# does not work.

As an example in the SampleData.json there is an ImagePath. In XAML, by default in the GridApp Template, you just bind it like `Source="{Binding ImagePath}"` and it's working fine.

```
// SampleData.json
...
"UniqueId": "Group-1",
"Title": "Group Title: 1",
"Subtitle": "Group subtitle: 1",
"ImagePath": "Assets/DarkGray.png"
...
```

But if I want to set the Image.Source I need to convert it to a BitmapImage or similar. Why?

Another question related to this is if I change `Assets/DarkGray.png` to `C:/a.png` it no longer show up. Is there no way to bind to images outside the project-folders?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part:

Xaml sometimes uses TypeConverters to convert values and figure things out for you. A good example for this is the `Foreground` property. You can say `Foreground="Red"`, and the system figures out that you meant `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`. If you do the same from code these converters aren't used and therefore it won't work.

The second part:

Every Windows Store app runs in it's own sandboxed environment. You can't access anything outside of it, except with some APIs. (file pickers, media library etc... - but most of these require user interaction.